# What functions can I use to investigate the nature of a column in a dataframe to see why it is causing unexpected behavior with the table1 function?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

Why is the *table1* giving nonsensical output? I have dataframe *data* and column named $date$ which contains numbers 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, or 2019. The *table* and *summary* functions both give reasonable outputs, but *table1* acts like the min and max values are both 2020, yet somehow gives a nonzero SD.

```
> table(data$date)

2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 

1171 1165 1220 1286 1313 
> table1(~date, data = data)

Overall (N=6155)

data$date

Mean (SD)   2020 (1.42)

Median [Min, Max]   2020 [2020, 2020]

> summary(data$date)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
 
   2015    2016    2017    2017    2018    2019
```

Why is table1 function in R giving nonsensical output for mean, median, min, and max (they are all greater than the true max)?

What functions can I use to investigate the nature of data$date to see if it is a property of data$date? Maybe it is a problem with the table1 function. I have never encountered this issue and was wondering if anyone had any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Show us `dput(head(data$date))`. The console print output of R vectors can be very misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reported infelicity that the package author is apparently unwilling to fix. https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1/issues/24

Solution is to increase the number of significant digits. The way to investigate such aspects of new packages is to see if they have a github page for issues. Two people have already posted issues of this sort.

Comment: TIL infelicity is a word. I found the time traveler from the 1800s. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=infelicity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: 'Infelicity' is commonly used in describing unexpected (often unfortunate) software behavior that is neither a 'bug' nor a 'feature'. I do not think the search function examines the content of comments but there were 70 hits to this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infelicity

Comment: And now I know how to use it. Thanks!